# generator from boost::spirit::x3 AST?

Tags: c++, boost, abstract-syntax-tree, boost-spirit

Esteemed Colleagues,

I've a boost::spirit::x3 parser (of an AST) that works fine for its purpose of bringing in input files into our application.

I'd like to flip things around and ask it to GENERATE output streams based on the same tree.

This is something I've never done. Should I use boost::karma, or just write a visitor/walker for the tree? What facilities does boost provide that might help me get started with either of these approaches?

I imagine that specifying the recursion depth globally, and at each level might be useful as otherwise the output could be HUGE.

Other issues for someone new to this to consider?

Thanks!

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. From the title I get that you want to walk the parser expression tree. Maybe you just meant to walk the AST. If so, please clarify the question (notable the title)

Comment: @sehe: Changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like Karma for X3.

There are no facilities outside the underlying Proto library to traverse the expression tree.

However. You will run into predictable issues where the mapping from input-output is not a bijection. You will always have to pick a preferred output representation for such data, which means that your data may not roundtrip, you might have a lossy transform. You need to take these into account.

I would actually not consider this. Instead of tightly coupling my implementation on implementation details of a complicated library¹, I would base my algorithm on the AST or datastructures that you actually control.

---

¹ like X3, which is also experimental, so things might change without notice

Comment: I appreciate your advice, and actually, you make a good point. Tightly coupling the input and output together is perhaps less useful.


I want a mechanism to generate lots of testcases for things that are downstream of our X3 parser. I can test the parser as well if I decouple them further.

Comment: I feel such a task would probably be best served with a perl script, or even better just manual input: generating will usually not find the relevant edge cases. Even _worse_: if you chose to generate test inputs from the parser itself, you would have self-serving test cases, and you're no longer testing anything (other than the compiler and library implementations)